# Cant push Owner's address into an array outside function

Tags: arrays

I am fairly new to Solidity and I wanted to understand the Push function better.
I am using solidity ver 0.5.12
I wanted to push the Owner address into an array as follows

```
        address Owner;
        constructor() public
        {   
             Owner = msg.sender;       
        }
        address[] playersAddressList;
        playersAddressList.push(Owner);
```

Remix is giving me an error stating
browser/Lottery.sol:53:32: ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' playersAddressList.push(Owner); ^

However, when I am trying to push the Owner into an array inside the following function **there is no error**

```
  function addPlayer(string memory a, uint b) public payable
    {
        playersAddressList.push(Owner);  

        address creator = msg.sender;
        playersAddressList.push(creator);
                    
        balance = balance + msg.value;
        require (msg.value >= 1 ether);
        
        person memory newPerson;

        newPerson.name = a;
        newPerson.age = b;

        players[creator] = newPerson;
        
    }
```

I wanted to understand why I can push the Owner's address to an array inside the function but not outside it?

Thanks
Rwiju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than declaring state variables and initializing them to values, you cannot have code executed outside of functions.

In fact, even the `initializing them to values` part is actually "moved silently" into the constructor function by the compiler.